# Can evaluation of functions happen during compile time?

Tags: compilation, language-agnostic, compiler-optimization

Consider the below function,

```
public static int foo(int x){
     return x + 5;
}
```

Now, let us call it,

```
int in = /*Input taken from the user*/;
int x = foo(10);     // ... (1)
int y = foo(in);     // ... (2)
```

Here, can the compiler change

```
int x = foo(10);     // ... (1)
```

to

```
int x = 15;     // ... (1)
```

by evaluating the function call during compile time since the input to the function is available during compile time ?

I understand this is not possible during the call marked `(2)` because the input is available only during run time.

I do not want to know a way of doing it in any specific language. I would like to know why this can or can not be a feature of a compiler itself.

Comment: You might find the `constexpr` specifier in cxx11 interesting reading.

Comment: @John3136 Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does have a method for this:

Have a read up on the 'constexpr' keyword in C++11, it allows compile time evaluation of functions.

They have a limitation: the function must be a return statement (not multiple lines of code), but can call other `constexpr` functions (C++14 does not have this limitation AFAIK).

```
static constexpr int foo(int x){
     return x + 5;
}
```

EDIT:
Why a compiler might not evaluate a function (just my guess):

It might not be appropriate to remove a function by evaluating it without being told.

The function could be used in different compilation units, and with static/dynamic inputs: thus evaluating it in some circumstances and adding a call in other places.

This use would provide inconsistent execution times (especially on a deterministic platform like AVR) where timing may be important, or at least need to be predictable.

Also interrupts (and how the compiler interacts with them) may come into play here.

**EDIT:**

> constexpr is actually stronger -- it requires that the compiler do this. The compiler is free to fold away functions without constexpr, but the programmer can't rely on it doing so.

---

> Can you give an example in the case where the user would have benefited from this but the compiler chose not to do it ?

`inline` functions may, or may not resolve to constant expressions which could be optimized into the end result.

However, a `constexpr` guarantees it. An inline function cannot be used as a compile time constant whereas `constexpr` can allow you to formulate compile time functions and more so, objects.

A basic example where `constexpr` makes a guarantee that inline cannot.

```
constexpr int foo( int a, int b, int c ){
  return a+b+c;
}

int array[ foo(1, 2, 3) ];
```

And the same as a simple object.

```
struct Foo{
  constexpr Foo( int a, int b, int c ) : val(a+b+c){}
  int val;
};

constexpr Foo foo( 1,2,4 );

int array[ foo.val ];
```

Unless `foo.val` is a compile time constant, the code above will not compile.

Even as just a function, an inline function has no guarantee. And the linker can also do inlining over multiple compilation units, after the syntax has been compiled (array bounds checked for integer constants).

This is kind of like meta-programming, but without the templates. Of course these examples do not do the topic justice, however very complex solutions would benefit from the ability to use objects and functional programming to achieve a result.

Comment: Thank you ! I understand, but question isn't specifically meant to target any language. I mean to ask why a compiler can or can't do it itself ?

Comment: Ok, I've added an edit with what I think, however its only my opinion.

Comment: `It might not be appropriate to remove a function by evaluating it without being told.`(assuming by 'remove' you mean remove the function call and not the function itself) - well, this is what happens when the function gets inlined , right ? And inlining a function is a very common optimization method.

Comment: `constexpr` is actually stronger -- it *requires* that the compiler do this.  The compiler is free to fold away functions without `constexpr`, but the programmer can't rely on it doing so.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Can you give an example in the case where the user would have benefited from this but the compiler chose not to do it ?

Comment: @MohammadGhazanfar I have added an edit with some examples of what I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, evaluation can happen during compile time.  This comes under the heading of constant folding and function inlining, both of which are common optimizations for optimizing compilers.

Many languages do not have strong distinction between "compile time" and "run time", but the general rule is that the language defines an "execution model" which defines the behavior of any particular program with any particular input (or specifies that it is undefined).  The compiler must produce an executable that can read any input and produce the corresponding output as defined by the execution model.  What happens *inside* the executable doesn't matter -- as long as the externally viewed behavior is correct.

Here "input", "output" and "behavior" includes all possible interactions with the environment that are defined in the execution model, including timing effects.